# How to create a working progressbar for cordova file-transfer

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

just a simple Question:

i used the Script from Raymond Camden [Progress Event in Cordova File-Transfer](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/5/1/Using-the-Progress-event-in-PhoneGap-file-transfers) and it works fine. It displays the percentage as a text which counts up till it reaches the 100%.

This works good, but it doesn't look fine. How can i create a progressbar, that starts by zero and counts up to 100% and has a green bar that grows?

Im not so good in javascript so i don't know, how to realise this.

This is my Code now:

```
var statusDom;

statusDom = document.querySelector('#status');

ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
    statusDom.innerHTML = perc + "% loaded...";
            console.log(perc);
            } else {
                    if(statusDom.innerHTML == "") {
                    statusDom.innerHTML = "Loading";
            } else {
                    statusDom.innerHTML += ".";
            }
        }
    };
```

and in my index i got a div container ->

```
<div id="status"></div>
```

hope someone can tell me, how to create a progressbar. It would be great if you give me a detailed explanation. Thank you!

Comment: could u help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784079/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-on-uploading-a-file similar question but i could not understand what is happening, and how this will get executed

Comment: That URL in the OP is now: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/05/01/Using-the-Progress-event-in-PhoneGap-file-transfers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the simplest way probably is to use the native HTML5 progress bar: `<progress></progress>` tags.

You put these tags where you want to have the progressbar and set `max` and `value` properties where:

- `max` is the maximum value the progress bar can represent when it's fully loaded (100% in your case)
- `value` is the actual value of the bar `perc` in your case.

So you put something like this in your HTML code:

```
<progress max="100" value="0" id="ft-prog"></progress>
```

Then you add something like this after `statusDom.innerHTML = perc + "% loaded...";`:

```
document.getElementById("ft-prog").value = perc;
```

You can build / design more fancy progress bars of course styling your `progress` tag in **CSS**.
You can get some nice ideas from here using **CSS3**: [CSS-Tricks progress bars](http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example with a progress bar. I am using it in my app

```
<div class="progress sell_progress_bar">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ upload_percentage }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{ upload_percentage }}%">
        <span class="sr-only">100% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the record I am using angularJS