# Show download progress bar ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, progress-bar

I am developing an ionic app. I am using cordova's FileTransfer plugin to download pdf file. I am able to download the  file to my internal memory,but not able to display single progress bar for downloaidng.
What is the best way of displaying progress for downloading.

**Controller**

```
var url = 'http://someurl.com/api/pdf_download/' + id;
// Android
var targetPath = 'file:///storage/sdcard0/' + id + '.pdf';
var trustHosts = true;
var options = {};
$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }, function() {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'No internet access',
            buttons: [{
                text: 'OK',
                type: 'button-assertive'
            }]
        });
        alertPopup.then(function() {});

    }, function(progress) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
        })
        console.log('progress--->', $scope.downloadProgress);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [cordovaToast](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/toast/)  plugin  for this feature.Here is the example for showing pdf download progress

**html**

```
<ion-view >
    <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-positive" style="padding:0px;height: 8px;" >
        <progress id="progressbar" max="100" value="{{ downloadProgress }}" class="progress"> </progress>
    </div>
    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**css**

```
.progress {
    margin: 0 px;
    height: 8 px;
    background - color: #F1292B!important;
    border - radius: 2 px;
    box - shadow: 0 2 px 5 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}
```

**js**

```
if (window.cordova) {
    var url = '{{base_url}}/pdf_download/' + id;
    // Android
    var targetPath = 'file:///storage/sdcard0/' + 'fpl_' + id + '.pdf';
    var trustHosts = true;
    var options = {};
    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
        .then(function(result) {
            $cordovaToast
                .show('File downloaded successfully..', 'short', 'center')
                .then(function() {
                    // success
                }, function() {
                    // error
                });

            console.log(result);
        }, function() {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'No internet access',
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'OK',
                    type: 'button-assertive'
                }]
            });
            alertPopup.then(function() {});

        }, function(progress) {
            var dnldpgs = progress.loaded.toString().substring(0, 2);
            $scope.downloadProgress = parseInt(dnldpgs);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As benka already answered to my question, you should use the `<progress>` html element.

The full answer can be found over here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/25553044/3671726